# Magento - injecting custom phtml block into 2columns-left.phtml not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

In my local.xml  file,  i have  markup to overwrite product catalog page. Inside of 2columns-left.phtml  before breadcrumb i  want to  create custom  category block with dynamic product category title, and  description and background color depending on category name.

Problem is that my custom  block not appearing.
local.xml:

```
   <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="core/template"  name="big_header" before="content" template="boilerplate/page/html/head/big_header.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
```

boilerplate/page/html/head/big_header.phtml:

```
<h1>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h1>
```

When i add this block  into:
    `<reference name="head">`
 content from big_header.phtml appear normally.

I use Magento 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local.xml in your theme layout folder as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
              <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
            </action>

          </reference>
          <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="big_header" before="content" template="page/html/head/big_header.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

Create templae as

> Your theme name => template folder => page folder => html folder =>
>   head folder => and big_header.phtml file

I think "boilerplate" is your theme name.

Make sure the category page which you are checking is `Page Layout set to "No layout updates"` in admin area.

Catalog => Manage categories => choose your category from left sidebar => go to custom design tab and Page Layout field.

There is no need to use `$this->getChildHtml('big_header')`;

Comment: Thank you for working solution. Mr Suman, i have  last question. how i can add custom block before breadcrumb only on catalog_category_view ? http://prntscr.com/dgx5o7

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses `core/text_list` blocks (such as `content`) which will automagically render all child elements.  Unforutnatley, `root` is not one of these.  You need to edit your template `page/2columns-left.phtml` and add a call into it for your block - i.e.

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('big_header') ?>`

Comment: I have changed local.xml:   `       <catalog_category_view>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
                </action>

            </reference>
            <reference name="content">
                    <block type="core/text_list"  name="big_header" before="content" template="boilerplate/page/html/head/big_header.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </catalog_category_view>` and added         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('big_header') ?>   into 2columns-left

Comment: Yes, and now you need to call the element in your `page/2columns-left.phtml` file.

Comment: but nothing changed - this custom block still not appearing

Comment: You've moved the block into `content` now, you don't need to do that

Comment: <catalog_category_view>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <block type="core/text_list"  name="big_header" before="content" template="boilerplate/page/html/head/big_header.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </catalog_category_view>  this doesnt change  anything - i still dont see new block - http://prntscr.com/dfl0r9